# How to compute the following loop in lua?

Tags: loops, lua, iteration, integration

So the question that was given was to compute the area of an integral using lua (and this method involves trapezium rule) - and this was broken up into a few steps and the part which i'm wondering is this:

> If `nsubt > 1`, the value returned is: `h` times the sum of `f(a_i)` for `i=1,3,...,nsub-1` where `h = (b-a)/nsub` and `a_i = a+h*i` for all `i`

But then it comes with the following instructions of this:

> do not calculate the values `a_i` by repeatedly adding h to the previous `a_i`.

So i was hoping if someone could tell me what to use instead of a normal loop

Thank you

Comment: make loop with variable `i` and calculate `a_i = a+h*i`

Comment: but does it not say not to calculate repeatedly? @EgorSkriptunoff

Comment: `a_i = a_(i-1) + h` is prohibited.  But `a_i = a+h*i` is allowed.